# Converting table with columns of monthly data into single row of monthly data

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I have a large table of sales data with multiple columns of descriptions and then columns for the each of the 12 months.  I would like to keep the multiple descriptor columns but combine the monthly data into one column.

I use excel for mac and not a regular user of vba. I know it can be done with formulas like offset but I cant figure it out.  Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Check also [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Excel for Mac doesnt have power query

Comment: Isn't this just a =SUM() task?

Comment: Ok. Depends on your version. But it does https://www.poweredsolutions.co/2019/07/15/power-query-in-excel-for-mac-first-impressions/

Answer (score 0):

In Excel parlance: you want to "unpivot" the month columns.  A simple task in PowerQuery which you "should" have available.

This is the same thing as "normalising".  You'll want to use VBA and this SO question provides a solution to the question I just begged.

[Fast Way to Normalize Data with VBA (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552075/fast-way-to-normalize-data-with-vba-excel)